# Version 2.3 API Image Import with a path and not base64

Tags: api, product-images, import

I am using the catalogProductRepositoryV1 (/V1/products) for importing a bunch of products (about 9.000). We have a very high fluctuation of products per day/import. So I would like to import images separated of those calls. I know, that the "media_gallery_entries" can import a Base64 string of the image, but with hundreds of products it would simply take too long.

**If I would upload the images to a specific folder, would there then be a way to just set a path + filename during the import of the products?**

That would have a way better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 REST API only allows base64 encoded media gallery inputs. It requires customization if you want to change the input as file name.

Try this [extension](https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images) to change the base64 input.

Known [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9280) related to your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply! I do accept that as an answer, as there is no other way as it seems. Sadly that extension is 2 years old, I just hope it will work with future versions, tho. I will try it out!

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to work :/ It's enabled but I am still getting the same error.